# How to format DateComponents as a partial date string?

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I have a `DateComponents` object that contains a month and a year and I'd like to have a formatted string from it in the style 'March 2021'. I've tried `DateComponentsFormatter` but none of the properties get anywhere near what I'd like to see.

```swift
let components = DateComponents(calendar: .current, timeZone: .current, year: 2021, month: 3, day: nil)
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
let string = formatter.string(from: components) // Optional("2,021y 3mo")
```

Is this possible to do from `DateComponents` please?

Comment: DateComponentsFormatter generally formats your date-time to quantities of time. You have to use ```DateFormatter```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let date = Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents())
var formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
print(formatter.string(from: date))
```

It's pretty much something like this you need to do

```
let components = DateComponents(calendar: .current, timeZone: .current, year: 2021, month: 3, day: nil)
let date = calendar.current.date(from: components)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"
let string = formatter.string(from: date)
```

https://nsdateformatter.com/ here you can see how to format the dates in different ways.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So I always have to convert it to a `Date` and then format that? Because converting to `Date` adds additional information (like the day of the month). But essentially I just don't display that part?

Comment: Yes. By saying MMMM yyyy in the dateFormat, you state that you only care for the month name and the full year